# Can't access elements in a nested template/repeating template?

Tags: javascript, polymer

I've searched for this and all the answers have been using Dart with which I have no experience.

Is there a way to do this with regular ol' JS?

`this.$.classname` returns only `null`.

edit: here is an example of what I'm trying to do

```
<template repeat="{{item, i in items}}">
    <div id="accordheader" on-click="{{toggle}}">{{item}}</div>
    <core-collapse id="collapse">
        <p>asdf</p>
    </core-collapse>
</template>
```

and the script:

```
toggle: function () {
    this.$.collapse.toggle();
    console.log('toggled');
}
```

I'm trying to make an accordion based on core-collapse, and while `this.$.collapse.toggle();` console.log works when it's *not* in a `template` with `repeat` as an attribute, it does not work when it is in a `template` with `repeat` as an attribute. I have tried both `this.$.collapse.toggle();` and `this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('#collapse');` and neither have found it in the repeated template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$` doesn't allow to access elements within `template if=` or `template repeat=`. Use `shadowRoot.querySelector('someselector')` instead. (not sure how the syntax in JavaScript is exactly, I only use it in Dart).

Comment: first thing I tried was shadowRoot.querySelector; no dice :(

Comment: I missed that you used $.`classname`. `$` can also only be used to access elements by id not by classname or any other selector. `querySelector` works always when your element exists. I need more information to tell why `querySelector` might not work in your situation. Either the element doesn't exist or the selector is wrong.

Comment: I've edited my question with an example of what I'm trying to do. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks for the response :-)

Comment: huh for some reason it worked this time.. thanks! :) I think using querySelectorAll was what was messing it up